# Send an array of JSON objects in the request body of a POST using the Alamofire request method

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an array of JSON objects that I would like to pass into the request body of a POST request to our server. However the method signature for the request method only takes a dictionary as its parameters:

```
func request(method: Alamofire.Method, _ URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = default, encoding: Alamofire.ParameterEncoding = default, headers: [String : String]? = default) -> Alamofire.Request
```

Is there a way to currently do this in Alamofire without creating the NSURLRequest yourself? Or is it in the plan for future development?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `.Custom` parameter encoding to do this or manually create the `NSURLRequest` yourself. Another possible option would be to modify the server to accept the array with a parameter name in the JSON.

As of right now, there are no plans to support this feature, but thank you for making us aware of this limitation. I have added the issue to our internal Trello board and we will discuss whether we would like to support this in the future.

Comment: Can you explain why there is no plan to support this feature? An array as the top-level element of a JSON request is perfectly valid.

Comment: To be clear, we've added it to our backlog, so that doesn't mean it will never be supported. It's just not very high on our priority list. The main reason is that it does not fit the other encoding types very well. While it is perfectly valid for JSON, it is not for a Property List and is not well defined in URL encoding in the query string or in the HTTP body.

Comment: Yep, I understand now, and after implementing it myself using .Custom encoding I can see why it wasn't done. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewJackman Could you please provide sample code? I'm struggling with it, thank you